# issue to select a PDF file from my mobile

Tags: java, android, pdf

i need to choose a pdf file on my mobile and upload the pdf file on a server, but i get this:" `no application can perform this action`"..why?

this is my code when i click on "select pdf file":

```
 private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_PDF_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an application for processing PDFs installed?

Comment: i don't understand sorry...can you repeat?

Comment: `application for processing PDFs installed?` @bradimus That is not needed. Just being able to pick a file will do.

Comment: You have no applications on your device that handles the action `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` you need a file explorer app

Comment: so i must install on my device a file explorer app? if yes what you advice me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install some file explorers on your device first.

Comment: what files of precision?

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand the question. What do you mean?

Comment: i must install on my device a file explorer app? if yes what you advice me?

Comment: Yes indeed. Try ES File Explorer. But try others too as they all give different file system paths or content shemes. Be prepared!